# Is there any way to test Kivymd app in Android?

Tags: android, windows, kivy, python-3.8, kivymd

I am developing apps with kivymd.
In kivy, you can test apps with Kivy launcher in Android.
But when I try to test kivymd app, it crashes.(it works well in computer)
Is there Any way to test kivymd app in android?

I'm using Window 10 and Python 3.8.
Thanks.

Comment: Build an apk using buildozer.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but I want to test app without installing (like expo's QR code)

Comment: You can build a version of kivy launcher with the libraries you want. I'd just build your own apk each time though, it's easier and faster than using Kivy launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Kivy launcher` is outdated for a long time. If you want to run `Kivy` applications from source directly on a mobile device, then I advise you to install `PyDroid 3` on your smartphone - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=ru&gl=US

Comment: I'm not sure that kivymd works well in pydroid, but I'll try it! Thanks!

Comment: I myself test applications this way.

Comment: I just tested my sample app in pydroid, and it works great! Thank you!